# Cohomology and Riemann-Roch in Number Theory (Neukirch Chapter 3)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In chapter 3 of Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, an analogue of the classical Riemann-Roch theorem is developed for number fields. To achieve this, notation suggestive of cohomology with sheaves of line bundles/divisors is used, however the exposition does not really further develop this "cohomology". In particular, we have the vector space of global sections,

$H^{0}(\mathcal{O}(D))=\{f\in K^{*}|\text{div}(f)\geq -D\}$

but there are no such analogues for $H^{n}(\mathcal{O}(D))$ for $n>0$.

Was such a cohomology theory ever developed? What is it called, and are there any references?

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking about sheaf cohomology, which is covered in standard sources on modern algebraic geometry, e.g. Hartshorne, Vakil, Liu.

Comment: @TabesBridges: the OP is asking for an "Arakelov-theoretic" analogue of higher cohomology, with the suitable conditions at the real and complex places. This is not covered by standard sheaf cohomology (even the definition of $H^0$ is ad hoc; it is not even a vector space).

Comment: Ah, I see the context now. The perils of pre-coffee commenting...